# Running leiningen update causes lots of warnings

Tags: clojure, leiningen

After I run `leiningen update` running `lein repl` causes the [following](http://lpaste.net/109614) output to appear? What am I missing?

Im using OSX,
Java 1.7.0_51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a leiningen bug - https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1625

You can temporarily downgrade (`lein downgrade 2.4.2`) to solve the issue